# Get only top-level folders in IMAP

Tags: imap

Is it possible to retrieve only the top-level folders using a `LIST` or `LSUB` command?

Let's say I have the following folders (C denotes Client, S denotes Server):

```
C: 0007 LIST "" "*"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Trash"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Sent"
S: * LIST (\HasChildren) "." "a"
S: * LIST (\HasChildren) "." "a.b"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "a.b.c"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "a.d"
S: 0007 OK LIST completed
```

I can retrieve subfolders of a specific folder by using the reference argument, like so:

```
C: 0008 LIST "a" "*"
S: * LIST (\HasChildren) "." "a"
S: * LIST (\HasChildren) "." "a.b"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "a.b.c"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "a.d"
S: 0008 OK LIST completed
```

However what I'd like to do is something that can return just the top-level folders, so that I can then retrieve the specific subfolders on demand, like this:

```
C: 0009 ???
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Trash"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Sent"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "a"
S: 0009 OK LIST completed
```

Is this possible to do, and if so, how is it done?

Comment: AFAICT the \haschildren and \hasnochildren are set correctly. a.b.c exists and therefore a.b \haschildren, a.b exists so a \haschildren, and \hasnochildren are set on all the others.

Comment: You are right... I must have been half asleep when I wrote that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIST "" "%"`

% is a wildcard that is not supposed to traverse heirarchies.